# It is quite weird for me that the equation of areas are represented in a trignometric way of electric flux density

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields, density, dielectric

[image]

I've been handling the electric flux tube above.

$$ S_{1}  :=\text{ area of the upper vertical cross section }  $$

$$ S_{2}  :=\text{ area of the upper vertical cross section }  $$

$$ S_{}  :=\text{ cross sectional area of the border of the 2 dielectrics }  $$

$$ \theta_{1}  :=\text{ upper angle between the normal line and the electric flux tube }  $$

$$ \theta_{2}  :=\text{ lower angle between the normal line and the electric flux tube }  $$

Currently I can't get the below 2 equations.

$$  S_{1}= S \cos\left(\theta_{1} \right)  $$

$$  S_{2}= S \cos\left(\theta_{2} \right)  $$

Can anyone give me some hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use little trigonometry to show the results. SEE THE FIGURE

[image]